# Why doesn't this getElementById function work?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="t">gf</div>
<div id="g">ds</div>

function $() {
    return document.getElementById(arguments);
}

$('t', 'g').style.color = "red";
```

Is there something that I did wrong. It says cannot call style of null...

Comment: What makes you think that [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementById) works with an array as the `id` argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function $() {
    return document.getElementById.apply(document, arguments);
}
```

You need to use the `apply` method to call a function using an an array as the arguments. The apply function also needs the context, so you need to pass `document` as well.

Also, `getElementById` only accepts a single argument and returns a single element (AFAIK), so this is basically useless. Not to mention even if it did accept multiple arguments to return multiple elements, you still wouldn't be able to use the resulting array in that manner.

Comment: `getElementById` does only accept one parameter anyway, the rest will be ignored.

Comment: This will work, partially. getElementById still only returns one element, so only the first one in the array will be referenced.

Comment: Hey that JSFiddle example is the same exact one I use! Same color too!

Answer (score 1):

```
function $(a, f) {
    a.forEach(function(id) {
        f(document.getElementById(id));
    });
}
$(['t', 'g'], function(d) {
    d.style.color = "red";
});
```